# How to use read_html reading a character vector of url

Tags: r, rvest

I am using **rvest** package, and belowing are the codes:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.zhihu.com/people/excited-vczh'
webpage <- read_html(url)
profile_data <- html_nodes(webpage, '.Profile-sideColumnItemLink') 
profile_data_text <- html_text(profile_data)
```

The codes read one single url and parse. What if I have a charactor vector which storing **multiple urls**. How should I put these urls to the above codes?
For instance, **urlist** is a charactor storing 1000 urls. How can I change my codes to scrapy all specific content in urlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `lapply` to run through each URL to grab the text you need:

```
library(rvest)
urlist <- rep('https://www.zhihu.com/people/excited-vczh', 100)
profile_data_list <- lapply(urlist, function(x) {
  webpage <- read_html(x)
  profile_data <- html_nodes(webpage, '.Profile-sideColumnItemLink') 
  html_text(profile_data)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I fixed the codes with lapply. But "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404." came out. What are the potential problems?

Comment: Looks like a URL issue where it isn't valid. My first guess would be it's got a typo. Add `print(x)` in the lapply to check which one it is.